# Displaying dates, number, percentages, and currencies in a local format

Tags: angular6

I had gone through the Angular site for Internationalization. But I didn't find any examples for this display format for date, number and currency in local format . It would be great, if I can get some inputs

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit too broad to provide a full and complete answer, however, I suggest you take a look at the `Internationalization API`. Specifically `NumberFormat` for what you seem to be asking.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

https://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization